# Confused by descriptor set errors

Tags: vulkan

I am working on a modular way to specify additional uniforms and samplers (e.g. descriptor sets) for use by Vulkan shaders (using generics etc.), but I am receiving multiple validation errors and I can't decipher their meaning or which Vulkan calls/data to examine.

I can't see where I triggered a mismatch or why a global descriptor requires (none) component type.

```
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-Shader-DescriptorTypeMismatch(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - Type mismatch on descriptor slot 0.0 (expected `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INLINE_UNIFORM_BLOCK_EXT`) but descriptor of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0, type: 0, name: NULL
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-DescriptorSetNotUpdated(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - Descriptor set 0x52 bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Descriptor in binding #0 at global descriptor index 0 requires (none) component type, but bound descriptor format is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM.
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x52, type: 23, name: NULL
...
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-DescriptorSetNotUpdated(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - Descriptor set 0xa4 bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Descriptor in binding #0 at global descriptor index 0 requires (none) component type, but bound descriptor format is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM.
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0xa4, type: 23, name: NULL
```

Comment: "*I can't see where I triggered a mismatch*" Neither can we; we cannot see your code, so we don't know why the error is happening.

Comment: I just want more information about the error and what the name of functions involved with descriptor sets are. I am not looking for a concrete diagnosis. And I wouldn't know what to post anyway since my codebase over a thousand lines of non-c++ : (

Comment: "*what the name of functions involved with descriptor sets are*" You called the functions; you *know* what they are.

Comment: I meant to say "which Vulkan API calls / datastructures should I examine related to these errors". I had spent a lot of time looking through my code and did not find inconsistencies. However - and as I stated in a comment under the answer - it turned out I was using outdated shaders and getting a bogus set of errors on top of it. I apologize for having a somewhat useless question on SO, the upside was though I was able to get help about a complex question and no longer have to pull out more hair

Comment: Perhaps I should unmark the answer and delete the question because it is useless to others? @NicolBolas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-Shader-DescriptorTypeMismatch(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - Type mismatch on descriptor slot 0.0 (expected `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INLINE_UNIFORM_BLOCK_EXT`) but descriptor of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER
```

Your shader interface differs from the descriptor type in your currently bound descriptor set at set 0, binding 0.

The shader expects some kind of uniform buffer, but you're providing a combined image sampler.

Maybe you're confusing a vertex shader with a fragment shader.

```
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-DescriptorSetNotUpdated(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - Descriptor set 0x52 bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Descriptor in binding #0 at global descriptor index 0 requires (none) component type, but bound descriptor format is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM.
```

You're either providing an image descriptor with a format for something that expects e.g. a buffer descriptor, or you're running into a known validation layer bug that is described [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/385).

Tracking validation layer errors in a big code base can be a bit tricky, so if you're unsure about how to fix them I'd recommend running your application through [RenderDoc](http://renderdoc.org), examining the pipeline state at the point where that layer error occurs or just step through the validation layers themselves. Using e.g. Visual Studio's locals watch window will help you locate the Vulkan objects that trigger these messages.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea there was a potential bug associated with my bad configuration

Comment: Turns out I had exported my compiled shaders to the wrong directory